# Pgfplots not plotting desired parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to graph a cycloid using pgf. In different viewing rectangles, the graph appears differently:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[red] ({x-sin(x)},{1-cos(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-0.2,xmax=2.2,
ymin=-0.2,ymax=2.2]
\addplot[red] ({x-sin(x)},{1-cos(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Add `trig format plots=rad` so that the arguments of the trigonometric functions are measured in radians.

Comment: Thanks! that worked

Comment: Note that `pgfplots` loads `tikz` anyways, so it is enough to just load `pgfplots`.